# django-autocomplete-light ModelSelect2Multiple not showing up

Tags: django, django-templates, django-autocomplete-light

My autocomplete field shows and works perfectly on the admin page, but when trying to generate it out of the admin, it shows as a thin vertical line. How can I fix this issue? [image: ModelSelect2Multiple field]

**forms.py**

```python
def student_form(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('student_form')
    else: 
        form_class = StudentForm
        return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form_class})

class CourseAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = CourseInstance.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(course_name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

**views.py**

```python
class StudentForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label= 'First Name ', widget=forms.TextInput)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label = 'Last Name ', widget=forms.TextInput)
    uni = forms.CharField(label = 'UNI ', widget=forms.TextInput)
    email = forms.CharField(label = 'Email ', widget=forms.TextInput)
    phone = forms.CharField(label = 'Phone number (optional)')

    time_zone = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = TIME_ZONE_CHOICES, 
        label = 'Time zone ')
    time_management = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = TIME_MANAGEMENT_CHOICES, 
        initial = 0, 
        widget = forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'display': 'inline-block',}), 
        label = 'How do you manage your time for assignments?')
    collaborative = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = COLLABORATIVE_CHOICES, 
        widget = forms.RadioSelect, 
        label = 'How collaborative are you?')
    academic_seriousness = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = SERIOUSNESS_CHOICES, 
        widget = forms.RadioSelect, 
        label = 'How serious of a student are you?')
    extroverted = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = EXTROVERTED_CHOICES, 
        widget = forms.RadioSelect, 
        label = 'How extroverted are you?')
    discovery = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = DISCOVERY_CHOICES, 
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    fun_facts = forms.CharField(widget=Textarea)
    course_instances = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = CourseInstance.objects.all(), 
        widget = autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='course-autocomplete'))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'uni', 'email', 'phone','time_zone', 'time_management',
                     'collaborative', 'academic_seriousness', 'extroverted', 'discovery','fun_facts','course_instances']
```

**urls.py**

```python
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name = 'index'),
    path('form/', views.student_form, #UpdateView.as_view(),
        name='student_form'),
    url(
        r'course-autocomplete/$', 
        CourseAutocomplete.as_view(), 
        name = 'course-autocomplete',
    ),
 ]
```

**form.html**

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %} {# assuming you have a content block within your <body> element #}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
{{ form.media }}

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see the field seems to work fine in the admin page, so I think the issue must be with how the form is being rendered.
[image: Admin page view]